# How to render an HTML page into an edittext

Tags: android, html

I am looking to render the html page coming from json.

How should i display all the data of html page in textview, containing all the tags like `<p>`, `<h>`, `<ul>`, `<li>` which do not have a class.

Comment: display into webview

Comment: Can you show the structure of your JSON? If it's pure html then you can use webview but if it's json then you will need to parse it and then render it.

Comment: For adding HTML page into your android studio project you must have to create Assets folder in it.

Comment: actually its html page content.. I want to display only specified contents into the textview

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution
Just in case anybody finds this, there's a nicer alternative that's not documented (I tripped over it after searching for hours, and finally found it in the bug list for the Android SDK itself). You CAN include raw HTML in strings.xml, as long as you wrap it in

```
<string name="nice_html">
<![CDATA[
<p>This is a html-formatted string with <b>bold</b> and <i>italic</i> text</p>
<p>This is another paragraph of the same string.</p>
]]>
</string>
```

Then, in your code:

```
TextView foo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.foo);
foo.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.nice_html)));
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this code but i also want to remove some text like the SOURCE CODE text. from the given html code

Comment: <p><span> features a rear dual camera setup.</span></p> <ul class="styled-paging"> <li><span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>SEE ALSO: <a style="color: #0070f0;" href="https://www.techgenyz.com/technology/lanmi-smartphone-xiaomi-launch-26th-july-named-xiaomi-5x/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">‘Lanmi’ smartphone of Xiaomi to launch on 26th July, to be named Xiaomi 5X</a></strong></span></li> </ul> <h2><span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>Xiaomi Mi Max 2 Specs</strong></span></h2> <ul> <li><span style="font-size: 14pt;">

Comment: sorry the SEE ALSO text

Comment: For <ul> and <li> you will need to create Html.TagHandler which will handle custom HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

**try this using webview you can display html**

```
 webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("",you html json code, "text/html", "utf-8", null)
```

**or you can use this**

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(html code));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
public String getHtmlContent() {


    String name = "APML";


    String s = "<html>" + "<head>"
            + "<title> My Test Document </title></head>"
            + "<body><p>Test content 1</p> "
            + "<h1 style=\"color:blue;\">"+name+"</h1>"
            + "<img alt=\"\" src=\"http://www.agarwalpackers.co.in/images/A-hai-to-assurance-hai.jpg\" height=80px; width=50px;/>"
            + "</body></html>";


    return s;
}
```